How can I total the data from two different columns with the same name from two different queries in Access to get a combined total?
I have two queries pulling same type by different criteria.  I need to add two columns that are named the same from each query and add them together to get one overall total.


Access Access via SQL, and use AS to create an alias for a column.
E.G
SELECT CountOfAgreementNo as COUNT250 FROM GT250, 
CountOfAgreementNo as COUNT1000 FROM GT1000
WHERE GT250.ContactNumber = GT1000.ContactNumber;

